# How to evaluate a double integral with two Dirac functions?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Here I have a problem, is the solution  the same if I integrate every one? part by part?

$$\int_0^Te^{-(s+\mu\lambda^2 ) t}  \int_0^l\left[\delta(x-R)\delta(t-tj)\varphi(x) \, dx\, dt\right]$$

I've already integrated but not sure about the result, I would like to corroborate it.

Comment: Does $R$ live inside $(0,l)$?

Comment: yes, 0<x<l, R is inside in x too, 0<R<l

Answer (score 1):

Separating your variables appropriately, we have

$$\int_0^T \delta(t-t_j)e^{-(s+\mu\lambda^2)t}\,dt\int_0^l \delta(x-R)\varphi(x)\,dx.$$

Since $0 < R < l$, the sifting property of the Dirac delta gives us $\varphi(R)$ for the second integral. The first is very similar since $0 < t_j < T$.

Comment: thanks friend! well tj, j is the sub index of t :)

Comment: Oh oops. I will edit my post. Is $0 < t_j < T$?

Comment: so, is the same the answer with the integral in t?  $$δ(t-t_j)$$   yes, $$t_j$$ is in T too

Comment: Yep. It's exactly the same as the other.

Comment: okey, thank you very much friend for your help :)

Comment: You're very welcome :)